# How to create a Circular Style ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, progress-bar

I need help on implementing a circular progress bar like this:

[image: CircularProgressbar]

How should I implement the Circle to fill by increasing `Value` property?

Comment: the link in question is broken. Please insert an image in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Windows Process Bar / Pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015088/wpf-windows-process-bar-pie)

Comment: The solution is provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77262057/10249156 in JavaScript, and I will highly recommend having a look to get an idea/inspiration on how the same can be achieved in C#. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a couple of options - the first is to template the `ProgressBar` control. This turns out to be a little tricky. I wrote a blog post which describes how to [use an attached ViewModel to achieve the required effect](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/02/07/a-circular-progressbar-style-using-an-attached-viewmodel.html).

The other alternative is to create your own control from scratch. You could do the following:

1. Create a new user control
2. Add new Value, Maximum and Minimum dependency properties to it.
3. Handle the Value, Maximum and Minimum property change events in your user control to compute an Angle property.
4. Construct two 'pie pieces' in code behind (see [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PieChartDataBinding.aspx#two)) and add them to the UI.

Comment: And why not template the existing ProgressBar? CustomControls in WPF are lookless precisely for this purpose. Whats the point of having gone through all the hassel of creating a lookless control when you are not going to reuse it when all you need is a different representation of it in the UI?

Comment: @NVM, I agree with you in principle but some code will probably be required here. There isn't really an easy way to create a cut-out arc using the built-in shapes in WPF using pure XAML. If one were using the Expression Blend SDK there is an Arc shape that can do it pretty easily. So the OP will probably need to create some kind of control that can draw the pie's. But the implementation of the progress bar should be a template that uses this new "pie" control.

Comment: See my edited answer. Its not that you cant do it the way you suggest. I think in general its just better to write as little code as you can get away with.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is an old issue, but anyways here is my solution:

FOR WINFORMS:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CircularProgressBar : Control
{
    #region Enums

    public enum _ProgressShape
    {
        Round,
        Flat
    }

    public enum _TextMode
    {
        None,
        Value,
        Percentage,
        Custom
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Variables

    private long _Value;
    private long _Maximum = 100;
    private int _LineWitdh = 1;
    private float _BarWidth = 14f;

    private Color _ProgressColor1 = Color.Orange;
    private Color _ProgressColor2 = Color.Orange;
    private Color _LineColor = Color.Silver;
    private LinearGradientMode _GradientMode = LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal;
    private _ProgressShape ProgressShapeVal;
    private _TextMode ProgressTextMode;

    #endregion

    #region Contructor

    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        this.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;

        this.Size = new Size(130, 130);
        this.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 15);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        this.LineWidth = 1;
        this.LineColor = Color.DimGray;

        Value = 57;
        ProgressShape = _ProgressShape.Flat;
        TextMode = _TextMode.Percentage;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Custom Properties

    /// <summary>Determina el Valor del Progreso</summary>
    [Description("Valor Entero que determina la posision de la Barra de Progreso."), Category("Behavior")]
    public long Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            if (value > _Maximum)
                value = _Maximum;
            _Value = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Obtiene o Establece el Valor Maximo de la barra de Progreso."), Category("Behavior")]
    public long Maximum
    {
        get { return _Maximum; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
                value = 1;
            _Maximum = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Color Inicial de la Barra de Progreso"), Category("Appearance")]
    public Color BarColor1
    {
        get { return _ProgressColor1; }
        set
        {
            _ProgressColor1 = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Color Final de la Barra de Progreso"), Category("Appearance")]
    public Color BarColor2
    {
        get { return _ProgressColor2; }
        set
        {
            _ProgressColor2 = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Ancho de la Barra de Progreso"), Category("Appearance")]
    public float BarWidth
    {
        get { return _BarWidth; }
        set
        {
            _BarWidth = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Modo del Gradiente de Color"), Category("Appearance")]
    public LinearGradientMode GradientMode
    {
        get { return _GradientMode; }
        set
        {
            _GradientMode = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Color de la Linea Intermedia"), Category("Appearance")]
    public Color LineColor
    {
        get { return _LineColor; }
        set
        {
            _LineColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Ancho de la Linea Intermedia"), Category("Appearance")]
    public int LineWidth
    {
        get { return _LineWitdh; }
        set
        {
            _LineWitdh = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Obtiene o Establece la Forma de los terminales de la barra de progreso."), Category("Appearance")]
    public _ProgressShape ProgressShape
    {
        get { return ProgressShapeVal; }
        set
        {
            ProgressShapeVal = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Obtiene o Establece el Modo como se muestra el Texto dentro de la barra de Progreso."), Category("Behavior")]
    public _TextMode TextMode
    {
        get { return ProgressTextMode; }
        set
        {
            ProgressTextMode = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Description("Obtiene el Texto que se muestra dentro del Control"), Category("Behavior")]
    public override string Text { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region EventArgs

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        SetStandardSize();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        SetStandardSize();
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs p)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(p);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void SetStandardSize()
    {
        int _Size = Math.Max(Width, Height);
        Size = new Size(_Size, _Size);
    }

    public void Increment(int Val)
    {
        this._Value += Val;
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void Decrement(int Val)
    {
        this._Value -= Val;
        Invalidate();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                //graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent); //<-- this.BackColor, SystemColors.Control, Color.Transparent

                PaintTransparentBackground(this, e);

                //Dibuja el circulo blanco interior:
                using (Brush mBackColor = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor))
                {
                    graphics.FillEllipse(mBackColor,
                            18, 18,
                            (this.Width - 0x30) + 12,
                            (this.Height - 0x30) + 12);
                }
                // Dibuja la delgada Linea gris del medio:
                using (Pen pen2 = new Pen(LineColor, this.LineWidth))
                {
                    graphics.DrawEllipse(pen2, 
                        18, 18,
                      (this.Width - 0x30) + 12, 
                      (this.Height - 0x30) + 12);
                }

                //Dibuja la Barra de Progreso
                using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, 
                    this._ProgressColor1, this._ProgressColor2, this.GradientMode))
                {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(brush, this.BarWidth))
                    {
                        switch (this.ProgressShapeVal)
                        {
                            case _ProgressShape.Round:
                                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                                break;

                            case _ProgressShape.Flat:
                                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Flat;
                                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Flat;
                                break;
                        }

                        //Aqui se dibuja realmente la Barra de Progreso
                        graphics.DrawArc(pen, 
                            0x12, 0x12,
                            (this.Width - 0x23) - 2, 
                            (this.Height - 0x23) - 2, 
                            -90, 
                            (int)Math.Round((double)((360.0 / ((double)this._Maximum)) * this._Value)));
                    }
                }

                #region Dibuja el Texto de Progreso

                switch (this.TextMode)
                {
                    case _TextMode.None:
                        this.Text = string.Empty;
                        break;

                    case _TextMode.Value:
                        this.Text = _Value.ToString();
                        break;

                    case _TextMode.Percentage:
                        this.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (this.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    using (Brush FontColor = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
                    {
                        int ShadowOffset = 2;
                        SizeF MS = graphics.MeasureString(this.Text, this.Font);
                        SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, this.ForeColor));

                        //Sombra del Texto:
                        graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, shadowBrush,
                            Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2) + ShadowOffset,
                            Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2) + ShadowOffset
                        );

                        //Texto del Control:
                        graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, FontColor,
                            Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2),
                            Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2));
                    }
                }

                #endregion

                //Aqui se Dibuja todo el Control:
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
                graphics.Dispose();
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PaintTransparentBackground(Control c, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (c.Parent == null || !Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
            return;

        ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(e.Graphics, c.ClientRectangle, c);
    }

    /// <summary>Dibuja un Circulo Relleno de Color con los Bordes perfectos.</summary>
    /// <param name="g">'Canvas' del Objeto donde se va a dibujar</param>
    /// <param name="brush">Color y estilo del relleno</param>
    /// <param name="centerX">Centro del Circulo, en el eje X</param>
    /// <param name="centerY">Centro del Circulo, en el eje Y</param>
    /// <param name="radius">Radio del Circulo</param>
    private void FillCircle(Graphics g, Brush brush, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
        {
            g.FillEllipse(brush, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                      radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

1. Place the source code into a new class anywhere in your WinForms project, name the class '*CircularProgressBar.cs*'.
2. Compile the Project.
3. After Compiling you should see a new Control or 'Component' at the ToolBar.
4. Drag and drop this new control into any form and customize its properties.

Control Looks like this:

[image: Control Preview]

Enjoy.

Comment: +1000. works like a charm. Thanks for posting. saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 16):

It's a bit tricky but not impossible. Here is the my implementation using smooth animations to guide. Value converters should be used to create a CircularProgressBar.

[image]

**CircularProgressBar.cs**

```
 public partial class CircularProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        this.ValueChanged += CircularProgressBar_ValueChanged;
    }

    void CircularProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        CircularProgressBar bar = sender as CircularProgressBar;
        double currentAngle = bar.Angle;
        double targetAngle = e.NewValue / bar.Maximum * 359.999;

        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(currentAngle, targetAngle, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        bar.BeginAnimation(CircularProgressBar.AngleProperty, anim, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
    }

    public double Angle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));
}
```

**AngleToPointConverter.cs**

```
class AngleToPointConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double angle = (double)value;
        double radius = 50;
        double piang = angle * Math.PI / 180;

        double px = Math.Sin(piang) * radius + radius;
        double py = -Math.Cos(piang) * radius + radius;

        return new Point(px, py);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**AngleToIsLargeConverter.cs**

```
class AngleToIsLargeConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double angle = (double)value;

        return angle > 180;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Application.Resources>
    <my:AngleToPointConverter x:Key="prConverter"/>
    <my:AngleToIsLargeConverter x:Key="isLargeConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="circularProgressBar" TargetType="my:CircularProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:CircularProgressBar">
                        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="LightGray"
                                     StrokeThickness="1"/>

                        <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                  StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure x:Name="fig" StartPoint="50,0">
                                            <ArcSegment RotationAngle="0" SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                                        Size="50,50"
                                                        Point="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource prConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}"
                                                        IsLargeArc="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource isLargeConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}"
                                                        >
                                            </ArcSegment>
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Border Width="100" Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat={}%{0}, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Canvas>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

It can be more customized by adding a few more properties such as InnerRadius, Radius etc.

Comment: Yes it is !! awesome

Comment: pls how  to reduce the size of the progress bar you have pasted @Ali,

Comment: Is it better to ask a new question with the same code?

Comment: almost eight years after you posted this beautiful solution, I found it and I'd like to thank you for this beautiful and straightforward implementation. Thank you!

Comment: @Ali Tor  can you suggest me how to update the control so that the size is not fixed?

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at `ValueConverter`s? You can bind to the Value property in the template using `TemplateBinding` and use an appropriate value converter to change the value to whats is useful for a Circular progress bar.

EDIT:

In the template:

1. Add a circle fill with yellow.
2. Add another circle on top with color orange.
3. Use a value converter(or multi value converter) to return a clipping geometry (using arc segment possibly) for the circle added in 2.
4. Clip the circle in 2. with geometry returned in 3.
5. Downvoter gives me my repz back.

Comment: -1, This can't be achieved with a value converter. It has to be addressed in the visual tree.

Comment: I removed the downvote because yeah I guess you could technically do it that way. :) But it would be much much simpler to do this with a subclass of UIElement then stick that into the template of a ProgressBar.

Comment: Just because something looks simpler does not mean that's what should be done. Creating a new custom control for a built in one when all that is needed is a different visual representation of the original is really ugly for so many reasons. Its like building a WPF custom control without understanding what a custom control really is.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I agree that a circular progress bar should be of type ProgressBar with a modified template. What we are disagreeing on is how that template should be constructed. I think a reusable PieShape or whatever makes sense. It could be reused in a chart, a busy indicator, whatever. But the end result would be a control template that can be applied to a plain-old-progressbar.

Comment: Josh, I get what you say. The problem is that the accepted answer advises otherwise. I have a UI intensive app with a lot of custom shapes and I can safely tell you going the value converter route will be far far simpler and cleaner than creating a custom shape. There are a lot of things related to the WPF layout engine to understand when creating a custom shape class and I don't think OP needs all that complexity for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Your Namespace
{
    public class CircularProgressBar : Control
    {
        #region Enums

        public enum _ProgressShape
        {
            Round,
            Flat
        }

        public enum _TextMode
        {
            None,
            Value,
            Percentage,
            Custom
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Variables

        private long _Value;
        private long _Maximum = 100;
        private int _LineWitdh = 1;
        private float _BarWidth = 14f;

        private Color _ProgressColor1 = Color.Orange;
        private Color _ProgressColor2 = Color.Orange;
        private Color _LineColor = Color.Silver;
        private LinearGradientMode _GradientMode = LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal;
        private _ProgressShape ProgressShapeVal;
        private _TextMode ProgressTextMode;

        #endregion

        #region Contructor

        public CircularProgressBar()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
            this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            this.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;

            this.Size = new Size(130, 130);
            this.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 15);
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            this.LineWidth = 1;
            this.LineColor = Color.DimGray;

            Value = 57;
            ProgressShape = _ProgressShape.Flat;
            TextMode = _TextMode.Percentage;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Custom Properties

        /// <summary>Determina el Valor del Progreso</summary>
        [Description("Valor Entero que determina la posision de la Barra de Progreso."), Category("Behavior")]
        public long Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set
            {
                if (value > _Maximum)
                    value = _Maximum;
                _Value = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Obtiene o Establece el Valor Maximo de la barra de Progreso."), Category("Behavior")]
        public long Maximum
        {
            get { return _Maximum; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 1)
                    value = 1;
                _Maximum = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Color Inicial de la Barra de Progreso"), Category("Appearance")]
        public Color BarColor1
        {
            get { return _ProgressColor1; }
            set
            {
                _ProgressColor1 = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Color Final de la Barra de Progreso"), Category("Appearance")]
        public Color BarColor2
        {
            get { return _ProgressColor2; }
            set
            {
                _ProgressColor2 = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Ancho de la Barra de Progreso"), Category("Appearance")]
        public float BarWidth
        {
            get { return _BarWidth; }
            set
            {
                _BarWidth = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Modo del Gradiente de Color"), Category("Appearance")]
        public LinearGradientMode GradientMode
        {
            get { return _GradientMode; }
            set
            {
                _GradientMode = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Color de la Linea Intermedia"), Category("Appearance")]
        public Color LineColor
        {
            get { return _LineColor; }
            set
            {
                _LineColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Ancho de la Linea Intermedia"), Category("Appearance")]
        public int LineWidth
        {
            get { return _LineWitdh; }
            set
            {
                _LineWitdh = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Obtiene o Establece la Forma de los terminales de la barra de progreso."), Category("Appearance")]
        public _ProgressShape ProgressShape
        {
            get { return ProgressShapeVal; }
            set
            {
                ProgressShapeVal = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Obtiene o Establece el Modo como se muestra el Texto dentro de la barra de Progreso."), Category("Behavior")]
        public _TextMode TextMode
        {
            get { return ProgressTextMode; }
            set
            {
                ProgressTextMode = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Description("Obtiene el Texto que se muestra dentro del Control"), Category("Behavior")]
        public override string Text { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region EventArgs

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            SetStandardSize();
        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            SetStandardSize();
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs p)
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(p);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void SetStandardSize()
        {
            int _Size = Math.Max(Width, Height);
            Size = new Size(_Size, _Size);
        }

        public void Increment(int Val)
        {
            this._Value += Val;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public void Decrement(int Val)
        {
            this._Value -= Val;
            Invalidate();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    //graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent); //<-- this.BackColor, SystemColors.Control, Color.Transparent

                    PaintTransparentBackground(this, e);

                    //Dibuja el circulo blanco interior:
                    using (Brush mBackColor = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor))
                    {
                        graphics.FillEllipse(mBackColor,
                                18, 18,
                                (this.Width - 0x30) + 12,
                                (this.Height - 0x30) + 12);
                    }
                    // Dibuja la delgada Linea gris del medio:
                    using (Pen pen2 = new Pen(LineColor, this.LineWidth))
                    {
                        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen2,
                            18, 18,
                          (this.Width - 0x30) + 12,
                          (this.Height - 0x30) + 12);
                    }

                    //Dibuja la Barra de Progreso
                    using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
                        this._ProgressColor1, this._ProgressColor2, this.GradientMode))
                    {
                        using (Pen pen = new Pen(brush, this.BarWidth))
                        {
                            switch (this.ProgressShapeVal)
                            {
                                case _ProgressShape.Round:
                                    pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                                    pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                                    break;

                                case _ProgressShape.Flat:
                                    pen.StartCap = LineCap.Flat;
                                    pen.EndCap = LineCap.Flat;
                                    break;
                            }

                            //Aqui se dibuja realmente la Barra de Progreso
                            graphics.DrawArc(pen,
                                0x12, 0x12,
                                (this.Width - 0x23) - 2,
                                (this.Height - 0x23) - 2,
                                -90,
                                (int)Math.Round((double)((360.0 / ((double)this._Maximum)) * this._Value)));
                        }
                    }

                    #region Dibuja el Texto de Progreso

                    string percentageText = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value)) + "%";
                    using (Brush FontColor = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
                    {
                        SizeF MS = graphics.MeasureString(percentageText, this.Font);
                        SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, this.ForeColor));

                        // Sombra del Texto:
                        graphics.DrawString(percentageText, this.Font, shadowBrush,
                            Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2) + 2,
                            Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2) + 2
                        );

                        // Texto del Control:
                        graphics.DrawString(percentageText, this.Font, FontColor,
                            Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2),
                            Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2));
                    }

                    #endregion


                    //Aqui se Dibuja todo el Control:
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
                    graphics.Dispose();
                    bitmap.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void PaintTransparentBackground(Control c, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (c.Parent == null || !Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
                return;

            ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(e.Graphics, c.ClientRectangle, c);
        }

        /// <summary>Dibuja un Circulo Relleno de Color con los Bordes perfectos.</summary>
        /// <param name="g">'Canvas' del Objeto donde se va a dibujar</param>
        /// <param name="brush">Color y estilo del relleno</param>
        /// <param name="centerX">Centro del Circulo, en el eje X</param>
        /// <param name="centerY">Centro del Circulo, en el eje Y</param>
        /// <param name="radius">Radio del Circulo</param>
        private void FillCircle(Graphics g, Brush brush, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
            {
                g.FillEllipse(brush, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                          radius + radius, radius + radius);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

save this as CircularProgressBar.cs. and then rebuild solution. then from toolbox drag it to your form . and form settings as follow ...      using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace your namespace
{
    public partial class Form44 : Form
    {
        private int progressValue = 0;

        public Form44()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form44_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start a new thread to update the progress bar
            Thread progressThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateProgressBar));
            progressThread.Start();


        }

        private void UpdateProgressBar()
        {
            while (progressValue <= 100)
            {
                // Update the progress bar value
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    circularProgressBar1.Value = progressValue;
                });

                // Simulate a slower progress
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                // Increase the progress value
                progressValue++;
            }
        }


        private void Form44_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure that the thread is terminated when the form is closed
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }




    }
}
```

you will get perfect circular bar with % . also you can change width of circle from properties