# Arc progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-shapes

I need to make a **circular progress bar** (image below),
loading start from left bottom side up to right bottom side. Light-blue `(#E8F6FD)` color is empty state and strong-blue `(#1CADEB)` is progress.

[image: Arc progress bar]

I have tried some approaches, but cannot find the best one for this implementation:

1. First of all I tried using a `div` element with `border-radius: 50%;` and `border-bottom-color: transparent;`, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv7tyt9b/). In this approach I got a shape exactly like in image but the problem is how can I fill border with progress?
2. The second try was using canvas, and this approach is nice expect the reason that loader appears on the screen only after all `JS` loaded, I would like prevent this behavior and show loader immediately when page is loaded, 
   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh4pch06/)

So my question is there any another approaches that can achive **an arc loader** or any suggestion for listed problems.

Comment: How modern is your target environment? Does it need to work in IE? Can you user SVG?

Comment: I have a similar (but somehow different) answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28866340/1926369

Comment: Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/mLA7X/4771/ (pure CSS).

Comment: Or this one http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/mLA7X/ (using less.js)

Comment: http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

Comment: You can also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198304/count-down-timer-with-circular-progress-bar/31199281#31199281. But I would suggest SVG (even more than Canvas because Canvas is raster based whereas SVG is vector/shape based).

Comment: @IgorSkoric my target environment is modern browsers + mobile support

Comment: @zooblin can you review once more(when you get some time) the accepted solution for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) with [arc commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) to make the arc shape. The animation can be handled with CSS by transitioning the [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) property.

Here is an example, hover the arc to launch the loading animation :

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.loader {
  stroke-dasharray: .5 18 19;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 2s linear;
}
svg:hover .loader {
  stroke-dasharray: 19 0 19;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0.5 10 8">
  <path d="M2 8 A 4 4 0 1 1 8 8" fill="none" stroke-width="0.78" stroke="#E8F6FD" />
  <path class="loader" d="M2 8 A 4 4 0 1 1 8 8" fill="none" stroke-width="0.8" stroke="#00ACEE" />
</svg>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes to the transition property for browser support (more info on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)).*

Answer (score 5):

## SVG solution

Here is a circle animation with SVG and CSS only.
Creating this took some time to get the timings right XD
what i did was animate the svg path `stroke-dasharray`;
And rotated that so it creates you semi half circle loading.

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.load {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e8f6fd;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-dasharray: 200 300;
  transform: rotate(142deg);
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  animation: progress 5s linear reverse;
}
@keyframes progress {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 200 300;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 300;
  }
}
.spesial {
  stroke: #1cadeb;
  stroke-dasharray: 5 300;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation: circpro 5s linear;
}
@keyframes circpro {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-220deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px">
  <circle class="load" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />
  <circle class="load spesial" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is a solution using just HTML/CSS/JS:

the core implementation is purely based on **conic-gradient()** in CSS for more info you can refer : [mdn-docs-conic-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient), you should also know how [**absolute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) positioning works
plz refer to the below code snippet solution

**Demo:** [image]

**Addition Info**
for those who want to make the progress meter more dynamic as well as customizable by creating just one re-usable component, then you can have a look at the solution I have written in angular

**Demo**[image]

Source Code Link(codesandbox): https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/progress-me-6s9cxm

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function handleOnStartProgressMeterClick() {
  let testMeterPercentage = 0;
  const outerCircle = document.getElementById("outer-circle");
  
  // mock delay
  (async() => {
    while (testMeterPercentage <= 75) {
    
      outerCircle.style.setProperty('background-image', 'conic-gradient(' +
        '#00acee' +
        ' ' +
        ((360 / 100) * testMeterPercentage) +
        'deg, ' + '#e8f6fd' +
        ' ' +
        ((360 / 100) * testMeterPercentage) +
        'deg 270deg, ' + 'white 270deg 360deg)'

      );
      testMeterPercentage++;
      await delay(30);
    }
  })();

}
```

```css
.outer-circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: calc(100% - (10px * 2));
  width: calc(100% - (10px * 2));
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle" id="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle" id="inner-circle">
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="handleOnStartProgressMeterClick()">Start Progress Meter</button>
```