# styling a circular progress bar C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a wpf c# code that generates a circular progress bar, but I need to change it's size, suppose need to reduce size by factor of 2 or whatever. The only thing ii need to know is how to resize the circle, I have made some attempts, but all resulted in a deformed control.
The source of my code is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871263/how-to-create-a-circular-style-progressbar) by [Ali Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698517/ali-tor)
 In the following is my code:
[image]

**CircularProgressBar.cs**

```
 public partial class CircularProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        this.ValueChanged += CircularProgressBar_ValueChanged;
    }

    void CircularProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        CircularProgressBar bar = sender as CircularProgressBar;
        double currentAngle = bar.Angle;
        double targetAngle = e.NewValue / bar.Maximum * 359.999;

        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(currentAngle, targetAngle, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        bar.BeginAnimation(CircularProgressBar.AngleProperty, anim, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
    }

    public double Angle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));
}
```

**AngleToPointConverter.cs:**

```
class AngleToPointConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double angle = (double)value;
        double radius = 50;
        double piang = angle * Math.PI / 180;

        double px = Math.Sin(piang) * radius + radius;
        double py = -Math.Cos(piang) * radius + radius;

        return new Point(px, py);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**AngleToIsLargeConverter.cs**

```
public class AngleToIsLargeConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double angle = (double)value;

        return angle > 180;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Application.Resources>
    <my:AngleToPointConverter x:Key="prConverter"/>
    <my:AngleToIsLargeConverter x:Key="isLargeConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="circularProgressBar" TargetType="my:CircularProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:CircularProgressBar">
                        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="LightGray"
                                     StrokeThickness="1"/>

                        <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                  StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure x:Name="fig" StartPoint="50,0">
                                            <ArcSegment RotationAngle="0" SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                                        Size="50,50"
                                                        Point="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource prConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}"
                                                        IsLargeArc="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource isLargeConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}"
                                                        >
                                            </ArcSegment>
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Border Width="100" Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat={}%{0}, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Canvas>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Just from having a quick glance at your code I would change following lines (to double the size): AngleToPointConverter.cs: double radius = 100; App.xaml: <Ellipse Width="200" Height="200" .../> and <ArcSegment Size="100,100".../> I recommend to pass the radius as ConverterParameter to the converter to eliminate the need for modification each time the radius changes. Setting or adjusting the Canvas dimensions is not necessary.

Comment: thanks for your attempt, but when applying the mentioned changes, it seems that the arc starting point doesn't fit with the new sizes.

Comment: _<PathFigure x:Name="fig"
                                StartPoint="100,0">_ and _<Border Width="{Binding ElementName=Ellipse, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Height="{Binding ElementName=Ellipse, Path=ActualHeight}">_. Then add a name to the Ellipse: 
              _<Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Width="200"
                       Height="{Binding ElementName=Ellipse, Path=ActualWidth}"... />_ Since the ellipse is a circle I added a binding from hight to width.

Comment: I'm not good with styling, but maybe [this](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ProgressBar.xaml) will help you. This is a style that fully changes progress bar to cricular using just the style, no inheritance

Comment: Have you tried to put your `Canvas` into a `ViewBox` and set the `Width` or `Height` Property of the `CircularProgressBar` to a scaled Value? (eg. `<my:CircularProgressBar Width="200" .../>` for double Size and `<my:CircularProgressBar  Width="50" .../>` for half the Size)

Comment: Thank u all for attempts to help. You have solved my problem @LittleBit.

Comment: If anyone will ever want to play with radial progress bars, feel free to check: https://github.com/panthernet/XamlRadialProgressBar